# Channel to multiple outbound-channel-adapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a channel

```
<int:channel id="myChannel" />
```

for which I would like to route every message to multiple outbound channel adapters:

```
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="ocaOne" channel="myChannel" />
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="ocaTwo" channel="myChannel" />
```

My understanding is that the channel will effectively act like a queue but I want every message to goto BOTH outbound channel adapters. How can I change the channel to act like a topic?

**EDIT:**

I believe the answer is to use a `PublishSubscribeChannel` but I can't be sure (Source: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider to use `PublishSubscribeChannel` (`<publish-subscribe-channel>`) instead:

> The PublishSubscribeChannel implementation broadcasts any Message sent to it to all of its subscribed handlers.